# SOQL Socrata query datetime between

Tags: python, api, socrata, soda, opendata

May I know what is wrong with my below code ? I would like to query all where date_occ is between '2015-01-10T12:00:00' and '2015-12-31T24:00:00'

```
response  = requests.get('https://data.lacity.org/api/id/7fvc-faax.json?$select=*&$where = date_occ between 2015-01-10T12:00:00 and 2015-12-131T24:00:00')
```

I get the following error:
 Unrecognized arguments [$where ]

I realise the following doesn't work as well

```
response  = requests.get('https://data.lacity.org/api/id/7fvc-faax.json?$select=*&vict_age >20')
data = response.json()
data = json_normalize(data)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

But this works:

```
response  = requests.get('https://data.lacity.org/api/id/7fvc-faax.json?$select=*&vict_sex=M')
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few questions and answers posed in this one. Starting with your second query first; where you want to look at age above 20 years-old. Looking at the metadata (click the down arrow), the victim age is not numeric and is a text string. Thus, you won't be able to use operators like greater than, less than, etc. However, you can look for "equal to". The query below will work:

`https://data.lacity.org/resource/7fvc-faax.json?$where=vict_age = '20'`

*Note*: I've dropped the `$select` and am just using `$where` for simpler display.

Your third example works since you've set it to query a text field. If you want LA to change it to a numeric, click the "Contact Dataset Owner" under the ellipsis button.

Your first question on dates has a few changes. First, your single quotation marks were not aligned and some were missing. Second, the latter date is `2015-12-131T24:00:00`, which has an invalid day. Finally, the data on the portal does not have a timestamp, so you only need the year-month-day. This will work:

`https://data.lacity.org/resource/7fvc-faax.json?$where=date_occ between '2015-01-10' and '2015-12-13'`

Finally, I would recommend that you use the URL structure, `https://data.lacity.org/resource/7fvc-faax.json?` instead of `/api/id/`. The former is the proper URL structure for Socrata-based APIs.

Comment: that make a lot of sense. I've totally missed out the type of each column in the data. thanks for pointing that out. I've amended the quotation marks and now it works ! response  = requests.get('https://data.lacity.org/resource/7fvc-faax.json?$where=date_occ between "2015-01-10" and "2015-12-13"'). thanks again!